# Dynamic query to get count in node using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, dynamic

I am getting 5 fields from front-end like this

```
{
    "gender": "Male",
    "diagnose": "Any",
    "outDiagnosis": "Any",
    "city": "Any",
    "insurer": "Any"
}
```

I want to query count based on the if any one or more field is other than Any, it will add it in the query

like here i have gender: Male so my query will be

```
data.count = await ProfPatient.countDocuments({"gender": req.body.gender });
```

Can Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made 3 variable 1 to maintain count 1 to store key and another for value and i passed it in the query object.

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {

    let data = { //response object
        count: Number
    };

    let count = 0; // it increments count based on value recieved that is other than Any
    let list = new Map(); // it is used to set & get column
    let value = new Map(); // it is used to set value recieved from req.body object

    if(req.body.gender !== 'Any') {
        count++;
        list.set(count, 'gender');
        value.set(count, req.body.gender);
    }
    if(req.body.diagnose !== 'Any') {
        count++;
        list.set(count, 'last_ip_admission_disease');
        value.set(count, req.body.diagnose);
    }

    if(req.body.outDiagnosis !== 'Any') {
        count++;
        list.set(count, 'last_op_visit_disease');
        value.set(count, req.body.outDiagnosis);
    }

    if(req.body.city !== 'Any') {
        count++;
        list.set(count, 'cityname');
        value.set(count, req.body.city);
    }

    if(req.body.insurer !== 'Any') {
        count++;
        list.set(count, 'company_name');
        value.set(count, req.body.insurer);
    }

    console.log('count: '+count);

    if(count === 0) {
        data.count = await ProfPatient.countDocuments();
    }

    if(count === 1) {
        let q = {
            [list.get(1)] : value.get(1)
        }
        data.count = await ProfPatient.countDocuments(q);
    }

    if(count === 2) {
        let q = {
            [list.get(1)] : value.get(1),
            [list.get(2)] : value.get(2)
        }
        data.count = await ProfPatient.countDocuments(q);
    }

    if(count === 3) {
        let q = {
            [list.get(1)] : value.get(1),
            [list.get(2)] : value.get(2),
            [list.get(3)] : value.get(3)
        }
        data.count = await ProfPatient.countDocuments(q);
    }

    if(count === 4) {
        let q = {
            [list.get(1)] : value.get(1),
            [list.get(2)] : value.get(2),
            [list.get(3)] : value.get(3),
            [list.get(4)] : value.get(4)
        }
        data.count = await ProfPatient.countDocuments(q);
    }

    if(count === 5) { 
        let q = {
            [list.get(1)] : value.get(1),
            [list.get(2)] : value.get(2),
            [list.get(3)] : value.get(3),
            [list.get(4)] : value.get(4),
            [list.get(5)] : value.get(5)
        }
        data.count = await ProfPatient.countDocuments(q);
    }

    return res.send(data);
});
```

Please **Post**, if anyone has a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/), [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) and [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) operators to achieve this.

Below query will be helpful:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      doc: {
        $objectToArray: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "doc.k": "gender", // Replace this with your key
      "doc.v": "Male" // Replace this with your value
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $arrayToObject: "$doc"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPLayGroundLink](https://mongoplayground.net/p/II15g_IRYik)

Comment: Thanks. based on what you helped me with I modified my code and was able to complete my task.